# Crear boton por codigo asp y asignar un metodo javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy generando un boton por codigo (genero un boton para eliminar, hay un boton para cada fila de una tabla dinamica) y necesito generar una alerta para evitar que eliminen informacion por error.

```
 Button boton = new Button();
 boton.Text = "Eliminar";
 boton.Click += new EventHandler(encontrarEliminar);

 private void encontrarEliminar(object sender, EventArgs e){
   . . .  CODIGO   . . . 
 }
```

Encontre que la mejor forma de usar un confirm es mediante javascript. Aqui el codigo javascript:

```
 function Confirm() {
 var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
 confirm_value.type = "hidden";
 confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
 if (confirm("Seguro que quieres eliminar?")) {
     confirm_value.value = "Yes";
 } else {
     confirm_value.value = "No";
 }
 document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

Y se supone que el boton tendria que quedar de esta manera funcionando correctamente:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" OnClick = "encontrarEliminar()" Text = "Raise Confirm" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"/>
```

El problema aqui radica en que solo se le puede asignar al boton un evento de tipo EventHandler quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de asignarle el metodo javascript o si existe alguna otra manera de realizar el confirm.

Comment: Has definido el metodo `OnConfirm`?

Comment: El metodo `Onconfirm` esta definido, error mio en vez de llamarse `Onconfirm` el metodo que se usa es el que puse arriba `encontrarEliminar` pero si esta todo bien en el proyecto lo acabo de revisar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio es muy facil añadir eventos javascript, solo tienes que añadir un atributo al boton

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirm('Atención:xxx'))");
```

Si necessitas ejecutar alguna acción con el boleano que devuelve confirm, ponlo en una función javascript y llamala en el onclik

```
var confirmar = confirm("Atención:xxx");
if (confirmar == true) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ponerle una clase x al boton y le asignas el evento click en javascript algo como esto:

```
<button class='btn'>
   test
</button>
```

Y en javascript le asignas el evento click:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

btn[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
   var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
   confirm_value.type = "hidden";
   confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
 if (confirm("Seguro que quieres eliminar?")) {
     confirm_value.value = "Yes";
 } else {
     confirm_value.value = "No";
 }
});
```